How to base64 encode a png asset in expo 50 android production app
I have been trying to get this to work for ages and have tried many different ways to get this to work. I am trying to get a bundled asset in an android app, created with expo 50, base64 encode it so I can use it to create a PDF. It works fine in development but after building the APK it doesn't load. I am not able to use Asset from expo assets as that is for sdk 51 I believe. I have found threads elsewhere that say to prepend file:/// or file:///android_asset or file:///android_res to the resource identifier that is available from assets[0].localUri but none of these variations work, the issue is not that assets[0].localUri is undefined, it is that I don't know how to use this resource identifier to access the resource with FileSystem. I have tried unzipping an APK to look at the file structure but it is not like a normal android app, I can't see any mention of any of the image i am trying to use, however there are other images the app uses, for splash screen etc. and i cant find those either even though they do work. Here is a minimal version of the screen that I am trying to get working. I am greatful for any help.
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useAssets } from 'expo-asset';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';

const App = () => {
    const [assets, error] = useAssets([require('./assets/images/your-image.png')]);
    const [base64Image, setBase64Image] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadBase64Image = async () => {
            if (assets && assets[0]) {
                try {
                    const asset = assets[0];
                    const uri = asset.localUri || asset.uri;

                    if (!uri) {
                        Alert.alert("Error", "Asset URI is not available.");
                        return;
                    }

                    const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
                        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
                    });

                    setBase64Image(base64);
                } catch (e) {
                    Alert.alert("Error", `Exception in loadBase64Image: ${e.message}`);
                }
            }
        };

        loadBase64Image();
    }, [assets]);

    const generatePDF = async () => {
        if (!base64Image) {
            Alert.alert("Error", "Base64 image data is not available.");
            return;
        }

        const htmlContent = `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>PDF Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Base64 Image PDF Example</h1>
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}" alt="Image" />
            </body>
            </html>
        `;

        const options = {
            html: htmlContent,
            fileName: 'test',
            directory: 'Documents',
        };

        try {
            const file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
            Alert.alert('PDF Generated', `PDF saved to ${file.filePath}`);
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert("Error", `Failed to generate PDF: ${e.message}`);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Base64 Image PDF Example</Text>
            <Button title="Generate PDF" onPress={generatePDF} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    },
});

export default App;


You might want to use the ImageManipulator expo package. It has the option to save the image in base64 format.

I am trying to implement your suggestion but am having the same issue as before, how do I give the image manipulator a uri that works on a bundled android app? I have tried Asset, useAssets, I have tried FileSystem and copying the file to another location, I have tried requiring the path to the image then passing that to Image.resolveAssetSource, I have tried looping through all possible android paths I could put in front of the resouce indentifier using useAssets.

Maybe try taking a look at the getContentUriAsync. It is Android specific.
